# SQL adding new column that divides figures in other columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have been trying to operate this code for a while but to no avail - Any help is appreciated:

I have a listbox that has two columns with numbers in (figures are pulled from queries. In the listbox I want to add a third column that divides column two by column one.

My code:

```
    SELECT 
     Q_Manager_CHS_Total.tbl_CEAR_Name.CEAR_Team
     T1.Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.Backlogs
     Q_Manager_CHS_Total.CHS_Total

      (T1.Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.Backlogs/Q_Manager_CHS_Total.CHS_Total) AS AverageNumber
FROM 
     Q_Manager_CHS_Total
INNER JOIN (SELECT Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.Backlogs, tbl_CEAR_Name.CEAR_Team 
INNER JOIN tbl_CEAR_Name ON Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.CEAR_Team = tbl_CEAR_Name.CEAR_Team) AS T1 
ON Q_Manager_CHS_Total.CEAR_Team = T1.CEAR_Team
ORDER BY T1.Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.Backlogs DESC;
```

Any help trying to get this working is appreciated.

UPDATE: The SQL below works and shows the two columns, its adding the third column I cant seem to do.

```
    SELECT Q_Manager_CHS_Total.tbl_CEAR_Name.CEAR_Team, T1.Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.Backlogs, Q_Manager_CHS_Total.CHS_Total
FROM Q_Manager_CHS_Total INNER JOIN (SELECT Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.Backlogs, tbl_CEAR_Name.CEAR_Team FROM Q_Manager_Backlog_Total INNER JOIN tbl_CEAR_Name ON Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.CEAR_Team = tbl_CEAR_Name.CEAR_Team) AS T1 ON Q_Manager_CHS_Total.CEAR_Team = T1.CEAR_Team
ORDER BY T1.Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.Backlogs DESC;
```

Comment: Have you tried this in the MS Access query development window?

Comment: Do you get an error message or something?

Comment: Also: this `(T1.Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.Backlogs/Q_Manager_CHS_Total.CHS_Total)` won't work because `T1.Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.Backlogs` has 2 `.` in it.. like you're referring to both a table **and** a stored query/view. Should just be 1 table/query then the field name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Q_Manager_CHS_Total.tbl_CEAR_Name.CEAR_Team, T1.Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.Backlogs, Q_Manager_CHS_Total.CHS_Total, T1.Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.Backlogs/Q_Manager_CHS_Total.CHS_Total AS percentage
FROM Q_Manager_CHS_Total INNER JOIN (SELECT Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.Backlogs, tbl_CEAR_Name.CEAR_Team FROM Q_Manager_Backlog_Total INNER JOIN tbl_CEAR_Name ON Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.CEAR_Team = tbl_CEAR_Name.CEAR_Team)  AS T1 ON Q_Manager_CHS_Total.CEAR_Team = T1.CEAR_Team
ORDER BY T1.Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.Backlogs DESC;
```